# Finding good statistics for computer science matriculation (drop-out) rate

Tags: teaching, computer-science, reference-request

To satisfy my professional curiosity, I'm trying to find a reliable statistic as to the number of students that declare their major as computer science and graduate with a degree in 6 years.

I was wondering if any organization compiled data on a per-major basis.  I'd like the info partly to satisfy my own curiosity, and possibly use to motivate students (i.e. you made it through a tough class).

Comment: "number of students that declare their major as computer science and graduate with a degree in 6 years" - are you asking for the number of students that graduate with a degree *in computer science*? or students that graduate with any degree? That is, do you want to know how many CS students drop out entirely or how many leave CS?

Comment: I'm asking how many leave CS.  For example, if a student switches from CS to Management he would have "dropped out" of CS even though he successfully completed his Management major.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [National Center for Education Statistics](http://nces.ed.gov/surveys/bps/) in the United States surveys cohorts of first-time, beginning students at the end of their first year in post-secondary education, and then three and six years after first starting.

Per their official [report](http://nces.ed.gov/pubsearch/pubsinfo.asp?pubid=2014001rev), 59% of beginning bachelor's degree students in computer and information science in 2003-04 had either left post-secondary education without a degree (31%), or switched to a non-STEM field (28%) by 2009.

However, this number doesn't identify those who switch from computer science to a different STEM field as drop-outs. It also doesn't differentiate between

- students who persisted in computer science and earned a bachelor's degree by 2009,
- students who persisted in computer science but were still enrolled in 2009, or
- students who persisted in computer science but earned an associate's degree or certificate by 2009.

Fortunately, the NCES also allows you to create custom tables from this dataset using the [PowerStats](http://nces.ed.gov/datalab/powerstats/) tool on their website. (You have to create an account to use the tool.) This is a valuable tool if you're interested in exploring these statistics further.

Using PowerStats, I found out that among those who enrolled in a bachelor's degree program with a computer/information science major in 2003-04:

- 51.3% had earned a bachelor's degree by 2009
- Of these students that earned a bachelor's degree by 2009, 67.6% said that their major when last enrolled was computer/information science.

So, 34.7% of beginning bachelor's degree students in computer and information science in 2003-04 earned a bachelor's degree in computer and information science by 2009 and 65.3% did not.

Here's part of the data table I generated for this answer:

[image]